# How to set Dictionary in NSUserDefault in swift?

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary, sigabrt

I've a mutable dictionary (in form of [Int:Int]) and want that to save it. I would use NSUserDefaults like that:

```
    var myDic: NSMutableDictionary = [:]
        myDic = [1:2]
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myDic, forKey: "myDic")
```

but with that I get an error:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setObject(_:forKey:)` can’t accept `Dictionary` with a key which is integer type. The method requires property-list objects, but `myDic = [1:2]` is not property-list object.

There are two documents about it.

[setObject(_:forKey:) of NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:)

> The `value` parameter can be only property list objects: `NSData`,
>   `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`. For
>   `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` objects, their contents must be property
>   list objects.

[About Property Lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-SW2)

> And although `NSDictionary` and `CFDictionary` objects allow their keys to
>   be objects of any type, if the keys are not string objects, the
>   collections are not property-list objects.

If you set a integer-key to `Dictionary`, the `Dictionary` object cannot be used for a value of `setObject`. You have to use a string for the key like this:

```
myDic = ["1": 2]
```

Comment: Dayum, that's a great answer. Really like a boss man. I like you. Thanx a lot. Gonna try it as soon as I can..

Comment: ok it saves.. but how can i reconvert back to int and i want to add some objects to it too. I now solved it all by making a `let tempDic = myDic.muableCopy()`. Is there an easier method?

Comment: anyway, it woks. so: THANKS A LOT!!